# How to check if it's the last element in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop which get's the jobs name. Next to each job I have a button "Complete". When user click complete, it hides the job from page. User can do jobs in any order so he might click first, than last.

Once all the jobs are completed, I want user to automatically go to the next tab.

My question is How i can check if this was the last job in foreach loop. User can hide jobs in any order; so how I can determine if it's last job than go to the next tab.

Here is loop.

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) { ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default center-block">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class=row>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2 style="color:orangered" class="text-center">SIP</h2>
                    <img alt="" class="center-block"style="width:20%;"src="../../css/collecting/logo.png">
                    <h2 class="text-center"><?php echo $value['name_dvp']; ?></h2>
                    <h3 class="text-center">(<?php echo $value['region_dvp']; ?>)</h3>
                    <h3 class="text-center">D<?php echo $value['id_dvp']; ?></h3>
                    <h2 style="color:orangered" class="text-center"><?php echo $value['maintenancelocation_dvp']; ?></h2>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img alt="" class=" center-block developerlocationselection" style="width:35%; margin-top:10%;" src="../../css/collecting/route-select.png">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php

}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".developerlocationselection").click( function () {
        alert(2);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to keep a list of all jobs with a complete flag, then after a job in complete you need to check your list to see if all are complete or not

Comment: How does this “hiding” of jobs happen - are you talking about something client-side here? In that case, you would of course be asking the completely wrong question to begin with. Your foreach loop runs on the server, and is ancient history already before the first click on anything on the client ever happens.

Comment: Hiding does work on the client side. When click complete, it hides the job. But my question is because can complete jobs in any order; how i can determine they are ckicking the last job. Becuase at last job, i want javaScript to take user to next tab.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    if ($value === end($array)){
        echo 'Last';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the better option would be to follow what @musefan said. Otherwise you could try something like this:

```
$array_length = count($array2);
$current_index = 0;

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {

   $current_index++;

   if(current_index == $array_length){
      echo 'I found the last job!';
   }

   //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Wrong on so many levels. Eg.: $array2 = ['keyOne' => 'You', 'keyTwo' => 'Are', 'keyThree' => 'Totally', 'keyFour' => 'Wrong'];

Comment: @Eakethet you are right. I changed it to my original answer. :)